# Reading a Text File Line with an Unknown Number of Values (Java 7)

Tags: java

I'm just beginning to learn to work with Java, so forgive me if this question is too simple.  I'm trying to learn reading from a text file for the first time, and the exercise I'm doing is to create a text-based calculator.  Basically, in a text file, I write the operation I want to execute and the values I want calculated, and then execute the whole thing in a java file.

The method's I've been using, however, have only worked when there have been a definite number of variables.  For example, if the text reads "sum 5 10", then

```
if (command.equals("sum"))
{
    String a=calcScanner.next();
    String b=calcScanner.next();
    float A=Float.parseFloat(a);
    float B=Float.parseFloat(b);
    System.out.println(command+" "+A+" "+B+" = "+(A+B));
}
```

will give me "15", but not if there are more numbers.  What's the best way to restructure this so that it will work regardless of how many numbers need to be processed?

Comment: You can use a loop and check `hasNextFloat()` before reading the number with `nextFloat()` and add the number to a sum variable. It can spill over to next line, so a better method is to read the whole line, then use Scanner to determine the command and read the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
while(someScanner.hasNextFloat()) {
    float f = someScanner.nextFloat();
}
```

And if you want to add all the floats in the file, you could add them to an array and then get the sum of all of them in an array.

The easiest array implementation would probably just be an `ArrayList<Float>`

Or as the comment below suggest, you could add to a total after each loop. So

```
float total = 0;
```

and you could just replace your loop with this,

```
while(someScanner.hasNextFloat()) {
        total += someScanner.nextFloat();
    }
```

Comment: No point in storing array if there is no operation that needs to operate on each of the number separately.

Comment: @nhahtdh True, he could just keep a "running" count that is added to each loop. It all depends on what he plans on doing with the numbers I guess.